# how to delete an object in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to delete a task from the database, so I use the following code below. This is my delete view:

```
class taskDelete(DeleteView):
 model = task
 success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

and my URL:

```
url(r'^home/?<task_id>[0-9]+/$', views.MyDeleteView.as_view(), name='task_Delete'),
```

and the HTML code of the button:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.titre }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.objectif }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ task.theme }}</td>
          <td><a href="#"><button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" >edit</td>
          <td>
              <form action="{% url 'task_Delete' %}" method="post" >
                   {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{task.id}}" />
                  <button type="submit" value="delete task"></button>
            </form></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I clicked on the "delete" button, nothing happened. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also post the code for your `MyDeleteView` class.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake taskDelete is the MyDeleteView still same problem

Comment: Please don't post the same question again and again. If you have things to add then edit the original, unanswered one please.